# How to fix error "Warning: split() [function.split]: REG_EMPTY " from functions.php of wordpress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Using tanzaku in wordpress and get this error

> Warning: split() [function.split]: REG_EMPTY in /public/wp-content/themes/tanzaku/functions.php on line 232

Line 232 in functions.php:

```
else {
    // ... or get original size info.
    $upload_path = trim( get_option('upload_path') );
    $mark = substr(strrchr($upload_path, "/"), 1); // default mark is 'uploads'
    $split_url = split($mark, $img_url);
    if ($split_url[1] != null) {
        $img_path = $upload_path . $split_url[1];
        list($w, $h) = @getimagesize($img_path);
    }
}
```

How do I fix this error "Warning: split() [function.split]: REG_EMPTY " from functions.php of wordpress theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the actual problem might be this line:

```
$mark = substr(strrchr($upload_path, "/"), 1);
```

It searches some url path for the trailing path component, but it would fail for `.../dir/upload/` with a traling slash. A convenient alternative in this case would be:

```
$mark = basename($upload_path);
```

This is unlikely to ever be empty, thus eschewing the failing expode or split afterwards. (The string splitting is a suboptimal approach too.)

---

A complete workaround might be to also replace the  `$split_url = split($mark, $img_url);` with something like:

```
preg_match("#$mark(/.+)$#", $img_url, $split_url);
```

This will ensure the correct format of the $img_url and return the correct image filename path, or otherwise fail without error if it doesn't match.

Comment: I`m not quite sure what I am doing, but this worked $split_url = preg_match("#$mark(/.+)$#", $img_url, $split_url);

Comment: Is it supposed to be this $split_url = preg_match("#$mark(/.+)$#", $img_url, $split_url); or just this preg_match("#$mark(/.+)$#", $img_url, $split_url);